React MUI5 typescript theme palette cannot overwrite primary/secondary
My design team made a lot of custom palettes and extra properties. This wasn't an issue in JS, but this is being a pain in TS. I got it working to not throw me errors in this createTheme file, but I cannot use it as theme.palette.primary.hover. It seems like it wasn't overwritten.
This is the createTheme section
export const paletteTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: "light",
    text: {
      primary: ...,
      secondary: ...,
      disabled: ...,
      hovered: ...,
      selected: ...,
      focused: ...,
      focusVisible: ...,
      white: ...,
    },
    primary: {
      main: ...,
      light: ...,
      dark: ...,
      hover: ...,
      selected: ...,
      focus: ...,
      focusVisible: ...,
      outlineBorder: ...,
    },
    black: augmentColor({color: {main: ...}})
   }
});

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface CustomColorOptions { //I also tried straight-up override interface PaletteColorOptions, it made no difference
    main?: string;
    light?: string;
    dark?: string;
    hover?: string;
    selected?: string;
    focus?: string;
    focusVisible?: string;
    outlineBorder?: string;
  }

  interface CustomPalette {
    black?: CustomColorOptions;
  }

  interface TypeText { //extra properties
    white?: string;
    hovered?: string;
    selected?: string;
    focused?: string;
    focusVisible?: string;
  }

  interface Palette extends CustomPalette {}
  interface PaletteOptions extends CustomPalette {}
  interface PaletteColorOptions extends CustomColorOptions {} //This overwrites primary/secondary color options
}

In this code.

theme.palette.text.white Works.
theme.palette.black.hover Works.
theme.palette.primary.hover Doesn't work.

I'm kind of puzzled of what to do.
UPDATE
Upon testing, my code does work. BUT in my vscode IDE, it shows up as error. However, it runs just fine in my web browser :/

You should use theme.palette.common prop to make colours accessible then you can get them via color='common.whatever'.
However those colors work only for components that were passed thru styled function(e.g only mui).
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  interface CommonColors {
     whatever?: string;
     or?: { even?: { folded?: string } } };
  }
}

const theme = createTheme({
   palette: {
     common: {
        whatever: '#ff0000',
        or: { even: { folded: '#00ff00' } },
     },
   },
  })

<Typography color='common.or.even.folded'> ...

TS Palette extension:
// Define custom palette color 
interface MyPaletteColor extends PaletteColor {
   myCustomColor?: string;
}

declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
  // Apply it to pallete via extension
  interface PaletteOptions {
    primary: MyPalleteColor
  }
  interface Palette {
    primary: MyPalleteColor
  }
}


that is basically what I had in my post.
Are you saying we cannot add custom tokens into things like primary/secondary?
theme.palette.primary.hover in Typescript

added you example how to extend palette colors, but using 'common' makes it easier and more accessible, you define all the colors in common then you apply them to color schemas (PalleteColor's), you access common color via string ('common.my-color')
